# How to create new dataframe column with a character that comes from three other columns but only if present in a list, in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, mutate

I've been trying to do this with mutate(), str_detect(), but it's too complex and dont know how to do all the steps, please help!

I have a dataframe in which 3 cols contain let's say fruits, animals, or "none".

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | cat | none |
| apple | dog | none |
| pear | none | none |
| pear | apple | none |
| none | none | none |

And then I have two lists:

fruit <- c("apple", "pear", banana")
animal <- c("cat", "dog", "sheep")

I want to create two new columns in the dataframe:
col4 should display only fruits from col1, col2, col3. If more than one fruit, I need them separated by commas.
col5 does the same but for animals.
If col1, col2, col3 dont contain an animal or a fruit, I need col4 and col5 to say "none".

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | cat | none | apple | cat |
| cat | dog | none | none | cat, dog |
| pear | none | none | pear | none |
| pear | apple | none | pear, apple | none |
| none | none | none | none | none |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you what you want:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c("apple", "cat", "pear", "pear","none"),
                 col2=c("cat", "dog", "none", "apple", "none"),
                 col3 = c("none", "none", "none", "none", "none"))

fruit <- c("apple", "pear", "banana")
animal <- c("cat", "dog", "sheep")

df %>% mutate(col4 = apply(.,1, function(x) paste0(x[x != "none" & x %in% fruit], collapse = ",")),
              col5 = apply(.,1, function(x) paste0(x[x != "none" & x %in% animal], collapse = ",")),
              across(.cols = c("col4", "col5"), .fns = ~replace(.x, .x == "", "none")))
```

output:

```
  col1  col2 col3       col4    col5
1 apple   cat none      apple     cat
2   cat   dog none       none cat,dog
3  pear  none none       pear    none
4  pear apple none pear,apple    none
5  none  none none       none    none

``
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked... I have so much to study :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(list(col4 = fruit, col5 = animal), \(x, y) 
    df1 %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(.x, !.x %in% x, NA_character_))) %>%
     unite(coln, everything(), sep = ", ", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
     setNames(y)) %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), 
       ~ case_when(.x == "" ~ "none", TRUE ~ .x))) %>%     
    bind_cols(df1, .)
```

-output

```
  col1  col2 col3        col4     col5
1 apple   cat none       apple      cat
2   cat   dog none             cat, dog
3  pear  none none        pear         
4  pear apple none pear, apple         
5  none  none none
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(col = pmap(across(everything()), ~ {
    v1 <- c(...)
   tibble(`4` = toString(v1[v1 %in% fruit]), 
        `5` = toString(v1[v1 %in% animal]))})) %>%
   unnest_wider(col, names_sep = "") %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(.x == "" ~ "none", TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  col1  col2  col3  col4        col5    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>   
1 apple cat   none  apple       cat     
2 cat   dog   none  none        cat, dog
3 pear  none  none  pear        none    
4 pear  apple none  pear, apple none    
5 none  none  none  none        none
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("apple", "cat", "pear", "pear", "none"
), col2 = c("cat", "dog", "none", "apple", "none"), col3 = c("none", 
"none", "none", "none", "none")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: kinda worked, but I needed col4 and col5 to say "none" if no animals and fruits :)

Comment: @Pame It is a bad practise to use `"none"`.  I would use `NA` as it can be easily removed

Comment: @Pame updated but i would say 'none' will be an issue later

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code with `ifelse`, 
to make the code work we need to update the vectors `fruit` and `animal` with `none`

```r
library(tidyverse)

fruit <- c("apple", "pear", "banana",'none') 
animal <- c("cat", "dog", "sheep",'none')

df %>% 
mutate(col4=ifelse(!(col2 %in% animal), paste0(col1,',',col2), ifelse(col1 %in% fruit, col1, 'none')),
       col5=ifelse(!(col1 %in% fruit), paste0(col1,',',col2), ifelse(col2 %in% animal, col2, 'none'))
                          )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   col1  col2 col3       col4    col5
1 apple   cat none      apple     cat
2   cat   dog none       none cat,dog
3  pear  none none       pear    none
4  pear apple none pear,apple    none
5  none  none none       none    none
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by creating base R function. For col4 you can write:

```
fruit <- c("apple", "pear", "banana") ; animal <- c("cat", "dog", "sheep")

df$col4 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
fruits <- x[x %in% fruit]
if (length(fruits) > 0) {
    paste(fruits, collapse=", ")
} else {
    "none"
  }
})
```

and for col5 the function is:

```
df$col5 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
animals <- x[x %in% animal]
if (length(animals) > 0) {
paste(animals, collapse=", ")
} else {
"none"
 }
})
```